# MDT does not automatically select the correct task sequence on reboot of client system

Tags: mdt-2010, mdt-2012, mdt

I have a pretty good (*automated*) MDT setup (with no SCCM) but when the client computer reboots, it asks for the task list that it needs to execute. I want it to keep choosing the same task sequence until the task sequence is done (it reboots multiple times).

How would I accomplish this?

---

**Extra info:**
Server 2012 R2 Standard with WDS pushing the Litetouch WIM (x86 and x64). MDT version is 2013.

The task sequence is for deploying Windows 7 x86.

Win 7 x86 is a custom task sequence built from the ground up.

There are three task sequences available on the server.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "built from the ground up?" If by that you mean you created a task sequence , deleted everything and then put your own steps in, there's several steps in a default task sequence which MDT relies of to properly run the Lite-Touch deployment on a client machine.

If these steps don't exist, the deployment won't work properly.

When creating task sequences, it's best to add on your custom steps into the default task sequence.

Comment: I mean that I used a custom task sequence (template). I have it automatically run but it only displays the default "welcome" page and asks for me to chose which task sequence to execute. After I select the task sequence then it picks up where it leaves off.

Comment: It might be the best but not for me (I understand why it is the best). I need extreme control in what goes on in the system.